# All of a sudden -- tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused

Tags: linux, postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

For a few months all has been ok, but now I have a lot of:

```
mix phoenix.server

[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.302.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused                                    
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.303.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
```

on localhost.

But:

1. Postgresql is running
2. Its config is the same
3. The config of my phoenix/elixir application is the same too.
4. systemctl status postgresql shows everything is ok
5. nothing bad in the log
6. I can connect to Pg via Pg GUI tool

What's the matter?

```
$ netstat -tulnp

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 192.168.1.37:68         0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           25117/libpepflashpl 
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                25117/libpepflashpl
```

Comment: have you tried `lsof -i :5432` to see if another process is listening to this port

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul, updated

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)